# JDBC can't be found in Eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, driver, classnotfoundexception

```
public static boolean startDriver(){
try{
Class.forName("com.mydql.jdbc.Driver");
System.out.println("Loaded MySQL driver!");
}catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
System.out.println("Failed to start MySQL driver! JDBC not found!");
return false;
}
return true;
}
```

I'm trying to use JDBC with my Java project but I keep receiving a ClassNotFoundException. I have referenced the mysql_connector.jar that I downloaded from the MySQL website and tried everything! It's in my >Referenced Libraries folder but I still keep getting the error!

Answer (score 4):

`Class.forName("com.my**d**ql.jdbc.Driver");`
Ought to be
`Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`

Comment: MY LORD! How could I'dnt notice it. Thank you. I'll try.